# SQL Server 2008 R2 installation after SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, installation

I had SQL Server 2008 R2. But then I need to have SP1. I downloaded `SQLServer2008R2SP1-KB2528583-x64-ENU` from Microsoft website and run it. After installation everything was ok, but SQL Server Management Studio didn't work. I downloaded SQL Server Management Studio SP1, but no luck.

After some googling I decided to re-install SQL Server. I totally removed SQL Server and try to run R2 SP1 installer again. But got following issue:

1. SQL Server installation center opens
2. I click "New installation"
3. SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup screen opens and offer to install support files
4. Click Next
5. Progress goes to 100%, seems everything ok, but window disappears and nothing happens....

Logs:

- 04/29/2012 16:09:15.372 Attempting to run user requested action from
  local setup100.exe
- 04/29/2012 16:09:15.430 Attempting to launch process C:\Program
  Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup
  Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2\x64\setup100.exe
- 04/29/2012 16:09:15.463 Error: Failed to launch process
- 04/29/2012 16:09:15.513 Error: Failed to launch local setup100.exe:
  0x80070003

Does anybody know what's problem?

Thanks

**Solved!**

Goto "Programs and Components" and remove "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup". Then, run installer again

Comment: There is a log file in the logs directory where you want to try to install it. This file should contain information that gets you going.

Comment: Attempting to launch process C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2\x64\setup100.exe  - there is no directory 'SQLServer2008R2'

Comment: Add your solution as an answer to your own question and mark it. That way it's easier for others to see.

Comment: I am able to do that only in 7 hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Goto "Programs and Components" and remove "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup". Then, run installer again

Comment: Great, glad you were able to solve this.  Be sure to mark this answer as "accepted" when you are able.  That will help others find this solution.

Comment: I have "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup", but the problem is present.